# How do I say "did you watch the football?"

Tags: translation

With the World Cup on, this is a common phrase I want to be able to ask. Is it simply 你看足球了吗？Or 足球比赛？And do I need the 了 in this sentence? Including the 了 makes it feel like I'm asking them "do you watch football these days, as opposed to before when you didn't?" Or should I put the 了 after the 看 instead of at the end of the sentence?

Comment: users note (as suggested by question) 看足球 corresponds to "watch the football game"   （看足球比赛) for completed action: 你看了足球吗？ to denote change (new situation) 你看足球了吗？ there also is  你看了足球了吗？（２了） which can be shortened to #2: 你看足球了吗？

Comment: Most likely, I will go 你看足球了吗？， 你看球了吗？or just simply 看球了吗？every body would assume you are referring to the world cup, so there would not be any problems with those omissions.

Comment: 看足球 bkrs (Ru) watch the football competition 比赛, 竞赛, although 足球 only means football, also as intermediate 足球比赛 can be shortened to 足球赛 (你想看足球赛吗?)

Answer (score 1):

1. "你看足球比赛吗？" = "do you watch football match?"
2. "你看了足球比赛吗？" = "have you watched the football match? *" (看 is the verb, 了 is the verb particle indicates 'completion of an action-- 足球比赛 is the object that was being watched)*
3. "你看足球比赛了吗？" put the object '足球比赛' between '看' and its verb particle '了'. that make '看足球比赛' a verb phrase

If you want to ask if someone watched the football match, #2 and #3 are both acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

People recently are just referring to world cup matches as 球赛 which in English we might just call *the game*.

You already have the sentence structure down pretty well, so colloquially you could just say:

> (你)看了球赛吗？

or

> 球赛，(你)看了吗？

In day to day speaking the orders can be swapped for emphasis or clarity.

---

了 here isn't changing the state to the level that you feel like it is, because you're referring to a specific one ore two matches that have already happened - it's basically phrasing it into the past tenths.

If you remove the 了:

> 看球赛吗？

It sounds like an offer to watch a game together.

Answer (score 0):

Did you watch the football?

- 你有看足球吗？ (Might also mean: Do you watch football? Depends on context.)
- 你有看足球比赛吗？

Have you watched the game? (about a specific game)

- 你有看那场比赛吗？
- 你看了那场比赛了吗？

But it's more common to ask: 你有看世界杯吗？ Do/Did you watch the World Cup?